# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10039fb00)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Was working but now have error after updating to swift 3 and swift 4; attempt to restore but continue to have error

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore();
    let newCalendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
    newCalendar.title = newPatientCal.text ?? "Add New Calendar"

    let sourcesInEventStore = eventStore.sources
    newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
        (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
        source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue
        }.first! // <---- Error occurs here; removed "!" but still have error

    do {
        try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newCalendar.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "PatientTrackingCalendar")
        newPatDelegate.calDidAdd()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not save new Calendar", message: (error as NSError).localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let oKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(oKAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Learn to safely unwrap optionals.

Comment: Are you trying to update to Swift 3 or 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `source` property of `EKCalendar` does not accept an optional. But you should never force-unwrap an optional because it will make your app crash if the optional is `nil`.

I would change your code for setting the `source` to something like this:

```
if let aSource = sourcesInEventStore.filter { (source) -> Bool in
    source.sourceType == .local
    }.first {
    newCalendar.source = aSource
} else {
    // optionally set newCalendar.source to some desired default
}
```